# Mongoose Returns Null when searching by _id that clearly exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean

I'm new to MongoDB/Mongoose and have recently started a project using MongoDB, Node and Express and I have run into an issue where when trying to query with mongoose on an _id that exists the result is null. I've found similar issues but most state that mongoose is querying on a pluralized collection name, I have confirmed that is not my issue here by turning on debugging for mongoose and verifying the collection is properly named.

My document lives in the report db and customer collection, there currently is only one document in that collection.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c64881002ea07789e9444aa"),
    "fields" : {
        "Customer ID" : "_id",
        "First Name" : "first_name",
        "Last Name" : "last_name",
        "Contact Type" : "opt_history.contact_type",
        "Opt In Date" : "opt_history.opt_in_date",
        "Opt Out Date" : "opt_history.opt_out_date",
        "Location Opt In" : "opt_history.location_opt_in",
        "Location Opt Out" : "opt_history.location_opt_out"
    },
    "filters" : {
        "company" : {
            "validation" : {
                "required" : true
            },
            "query_value" : "company:%company_id%"
        },
        "opt_history" : {
            "validation" : {
                "required" : true
            },
            "query_value" : {
                "opt_in" : {
                    "if" : {
                        "start_date" : {
                            "if" : {
                                "end_date" : "{$and: [{\"opt_history.opt_in_date\":{$gte: %start_date%, $lte: %end_date%}}, {\"opt_history.opt_out_date\":{$eq: null}}]}"
                            },
                            "else" : "{$and: [{\"opt_history.opt_in_date\":{$eq: %start_date%}}, {\"opt_history.opt_out_date\":{$eq: null}}]}"
                        }
                    },
                    "else" : "{$and: [{\"opt_history.opt_in_date\":{$ne: null}}, {\"opt_history.opt_out_date\":{$eq: null}}]}"
                },
                "opt_out" : {
                    "if" : {
                        "start_date" : {
                            "if" : {
                                "end_date" : "opt_history.opt_out_date:{$gte: %start_date%, $lte: %end_date%}"
                            },
                            "else" : "opt_history.opt_out_date:{$eq: %start_date%}"
                        }
                    },
                    "else" : "opt_history.opt_out_date:{$ne: null}"
                },
                "no_opt" : "{$or: [{\"opt_history\":null}, {\"opt_history.opt_out_date\":{$nin:[null]}}]}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code used to fetch the document is as follows (FWIW I've tried both the string _id and the ObjectId and the results are the same):

```
exports.run = function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.query.id);
    const report = require('../models/Report');
    report.findById("5c64881002ea07789e9444aa").exec(function(err, result) {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(result);
        res.send(result);
    });
};
```

I've turned on debug for mongoose and can see that the query that is being formed is `customer.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("5c64881002ea07789e9444aa") }, { projection: {} })` and I have attempted to run that query in mongodb directly and get the following error.

```
db.customer.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("5c64881002ea07789e9444aa") }, { projection: {} })
2019-02-15T11:27:51.425-0700 E QUERY    [js] Error: error: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : ">1 field in obj: {}",
    "code" : 2,
    "codeName" : "BadValue"
} :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DBCommandCursor@src/mongo/shell/query.js:708:1
DBQuery.prototype._exec@src/mongo/shell/query.js:113:28
DBQuery.prototype.hasNext@src/mongo/shell/query.js:288:5
DBCollection.prototype.findOne@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:260:10
@(shell):1:1
```

It seems that the problem is with the "projection: {}" that mongoose appears to be injecting into my query. When I remove that piece the query will run fine in mongodb. So the question is, why does mongoose do this and what can I do to suppress it? I want the entire document so I don't need to project any fields.

Comment: There error in the console is that you need to have at least 1 field in your projection.

Comment: ok, I tried that and got an error stating "Unsupported projection option: projection {filters: 1.0}". If I remove the "projection; { filters: 1.0}" part from the query it runs just fine. So it appears I don't actually need a projection which begs the question why is mongoose adding one when I'm not telling it to?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it turns out I was trying to improperly switch dbs on my mongoose connection so the document I was searching for never actually existed because I was searching in the wrong db (at the time both DB's had a collection with the same name but that is changing).